# $ not defined in ADF jsff page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, iframe, oracle-adf

I have a jsff page created in ADF, which is using jquery

```
Following is the code:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html">   

<af:resource type="javascript" source="/js/libs/slickgrid/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></af:resource>    
<af:resource type="javascript" source="/js/libs/slickgrid/scripts/jquery.event.drag-2.3.0.js"></af:resource>

<af:resource type="javascript">

    function addColumns(accNames,movmentRows,jsonString){
          var frameComp = $('[id*="slickFrame"]',document)[0].id;              document.getElementById(frameComp).contentWindow.addColumns(accNames,movmentRows,jsonString);              
        }
    function triggerOnLoad(evt){         
      console.log('onLoad');
      AdfCustomEvent.queue(evt.getSource(), "onLoadEvt",{},false);
      return true;
    }
```

```
<af:panelStretchLayout id="tarConfig" topHeight="50px" startWidth="20px"
                           endWidth="10px" bottomHeight="0px">
        <f:facet name="center">
            <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical"
                                 xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
                                 id="panelGrp">


                <af:inlineFrame id="slickFrame" 
                                source="/js/views/tarAutomation.html"                                
                                sizing="preferred" shortDesc="Slick Grid" >
                    <af:serverListener type="onLoadEvt" method="#{pageFlowScope.TrcsTARAutomationCustomUIBean.initializeGrid}" />
                    <af:clientListener method="triggerOnLoad" type="inlineFrameLoad"/>
                </af:inlineFrame>
</af:panelStretchLayout>
```

Locally this works fine but when loaded on a server it fails with this error:

VM2490:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined and this is occurring because of the line in function addColumns(accNames,movmentRows,jsonString)

In the server i have checked, jquery lib is loaded in the correct path.
I dont understand why its not able to recognize the $

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Asha